# @Reference from Servlet Filter

Tags: osgi, servlet-filters, liferay-7

I am writing a Servlet Filter and would like to use one of my Liferay components using @Reference:

```
package my.filter;

import my.Compo;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(...) {
        compo.doTheThing();
    }

    @Reference(unbind = "-")
    protected my.Compo compo;
}
```

I get this Java compilation error:

```
annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is it maybe impossible to achieve this?

Comment: 1. You can't use \@Reference outside of osgi \@Components. 2. Did you define this dependency ogr.osgi:org.osgi.service.component.annotations:1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

As tipped by Miroslav, @Reference can only be used in an OSGi component, and a servlet filter is not one.

The solution in Liferay 7 is to develop a filter component.
The procedure to do so is explained at http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-dxp-filter-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple filer like: https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/filters-in-liferay-7 and http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-dxp-filter-tutorial/

But you can also use regular filters, as long you configure you Liferay webapp for that -> there are two consequences if you use regular filters though: you will be out of osgi application and you will have to keep track of this whenever you update your bundle. That is why you should not go with regular implementation. (just complementing the OP answer with the underlining reason to avoid the initial track)